# Returning the row number for a query to a different Google sheet

Tags: jquery, google-sheets, row-number

I am trying to retrieve the row number along with multiple cell data from a different sheet than the one I am in. I have the query that returns all of the column values I need but I can't seem to figure out how to get the row number to come with it.

This is my equation

=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abunchofnumbersandsuch/","'2018 Data Log'!B2:O"), "select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10, Col11, Col12, Col13, Col14 where Col4 contains '"&'Data Entry'!C4&"'", 0)

it queries a different sheet based on the value from the "Data Entry" sheet in the current "workbook?" I'm an excel guy so not sure if that's the correct syntax. I have tried placing row() different spots in the equation but I just can't seem to get it to work.

example
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(ROW(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abunchofnumbersandsuch/","'2018 Data Log'!B2:O"), "select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10, Col11, Col12, Col13, Col14 where Col4 contains '"&'Data Entry'!C4&"'", 0)

Answer (score 0):

The `importrange()` function gets an array rather than a range. Row numbers can only be retrieved from a range. In order to copy data with row numbers, you must store those row numbers next to the data you are importing before you import, or recreate the row numbers using some logic.

If you cannot modify the source spreadsheet, one easy workaround would be to import *all* of the data to a new `'Import'` sheet in the target spreadsheet, add row numbers there, and then use `query()` or `filter()` to aggregate the data the way you need. You can import the data with this formula in cell `Import!A1`:

```
=importdata("abunchofnumbersandsuch", "2018 Data Log!A1:O")
```

Then point `query()`, `filter()`, `row()` at the `'Import'` sheet. To more easily access row numbers, use `filter()` instead of `query()`, like this:

```
=filter( 
  { Import!B2:O, row(Import!B2:O) }, 
  Import!E2:E = 'Data Entry'!C4 
)
```

In the event you are copying data from one sheet to another within the same spreadsheet file, you should not use `importrange()` in the first place.

See [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197).

Comment: the import range is from a totally different file, not a different sheet in the same file.

Comment: Edited the answer. Please edit the question to clarify it.